# how to empty the function parameter once it passes to the function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send the parameter in a function but its in a loop so when i select the same function next time it first send me the previous value then send me the value that i want which causes the function to be empty and not take any value let me show you my code.

```js
$(window).load(function(e) {
  loadmore();
  select_likes();
  select_share();
  // get_recieve_friend_requests();
  // get_sent_friend_requests();
});

function loadmore() {
  var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastID');
  // alert(lastID);

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo base_url("user/get_all_post"); ?>',
    data: {
      id: lastID
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(data) {
      $('.load-more').show();
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);
      var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);

      if (json == "") {
        $("#bottom").append('<div class="btn btn-default col-md-6" >' + 'No More Results' + '</div>');
        $("#Load_more_data").hide();
      } else {
        $postID = json[json.length - 1].id;
        $('.load-more').attr('lastID', $postID);
        $.each(json, function(key, data) {
          var post_id = data.id;
          var post_status = data.status;
          var status_image = data.status_image;
          var multimage = data.multimage;

          if (!post_status == "" && !status_image == "") {
            alert(post_id);
            $("#status_data").append('<div class="media-body"><div class="input-group"><form action="" id="form_content_multimage"><textarea name="textdata" id="content_comment_multimage" cols="25" rows="1"  class="form-control message"  placeholder="Whats on your mind ?"></textarea><button type="submit" id="comment_button_multimage" onclick="comment_here_multimage(' + post_id + ');" >Comment</button><?php echo form_close();?></div></div></li></ul></div></div>');
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
}

function comment_here_multimage(post_id) {
  $(document).on('click', '#comment_button_multimage', function(e) {
    // this will prevent form and reload page on submit.
    e.preventDefault();
    var post_id_multimage = $('#post_id_multimage').val();
    // here you will get Post ID
    alert(post_id_multimage);
    var Post_id = post_id;
    alert(post_id);

    if (post_id == post_id_multimage) {
      var User_id = $('.id_data').attr('value');
      var textdata = $('#content_comment_multimage').val();
      alert(textdata);
      alert(Post_id);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url("user/post_comment"); ?>',
        data: {
          Post_id: Post_id,
          User_id: User_id,
          textdata: textdata
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          alert('you have like this');
          jQuery('#form_content_multimage')[0].reset();
          Post_id = "";
        }
      });
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

The post_id is being passed onclick event of the comment_here_multimage but whenver i click on it after first time same id is being passed again first then the next id passes. what can i fo to empty the post_id value once it completes.

look at these images and tell me if there is something you dont understand.

```
[![first time comment][1]][1]     
[![second time comment][2]][2]
[![second time comment][3]][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b36o4.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahg3W.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/taHAS.png
```

Comment: Can you isolate the issue better? I did not manage to understand what you trying do to neither what is the issue.

Comment: in your html there is different values of append divs after execution of post function?

Comment: please look at the edited @rafaelxy

Comment: please look at the edited @bxN5

Comment: You are not sharing you html structure. I am guessing that you are using multiple html id's (#post_id_multimage) which should be unique in the DOM. If you have more than one the selector probably will always get the first.

Comment: how can get the selector to slect the next id ? @rafaelxy

Comment: According to HTML's (4 and 5) specification you should not use multiple id's with the same name. They should be unique. If you have multiple elements use a class or other attribute.

Comment: but i need to change the value of my post_id whenever the post changes how would it help me to change the class? @rafaelxy

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not isolated in code. However according to my understanding.

You are binding "comment_here_multimage" function on click event of button when creating dynamic html.
Once context is loaded and user clicks that button you again binds another function on same button, which is ultimately added to the event stack.

If user clicks the button first time nothing will happen, there is no action on it. On first time it will register a handler with it.
If user click second time it will fire the handler attached on first click resulting in old postid supplied to it.

I think your problem is with passing parameter. You can set it in a custom parameter and get it later in click handler. Or you can change your handler like below.

You can change your code like this

```
onclick="comment_here_multimage(this,' + post_id + ');"

    function comment_here_multimage(e,post_id) {

    // this will prevent form and reload page on submit.
    e.preventDefault();
    var post_id_multimage = $('#post_id_multimage').val();
    // here you will get Post ID
    alert(post_id_multimage);
    var Post_id = post_id;
    alert(post_id);

    if (post_id == post_id_multimage) {
      var User_id = $('.id_data').attr('value');
      var textdata = $('#content_comment_multimage').val();
      alert(textdata);
      alert(Post_id);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url("user/post_comment"); ?>',
        data: {
          Post_id: Post_id,
          User_id: User_id,
          textdata: textdata
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          alert('you have like this');
          jQuery('#form_content_multimage')[0].reset();
          Post_id = "";
        }
      });
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  ;
}
```

Comment: its only reloading my page and not working @Mudassar Hasnain

Comment: onclick="comment_here_multimage(this,' + post_id + ');" have you changed this line in your append div code as well

Comment: i need to enter the value in my database first for that i need the selector to select the value but its not working @Mudassar Hasnain

Comment: my bad please pass event instead of this onclick="comment_here_multimage(event,' + post_id + ');"  i think this will solve your problem